# UISwipeGestureRecognizer on view - If a touch is inside a UITableViewCell how to pass it to the cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I added a UISwipeGestureRecognizer to my view which changes the content of the view depending on the direction the user swipes(left or right). If a user swipes in a UITableViewCell though, the touch gets ignored and the swipe to delete feature never shows up. How do I pass this touch to the UITableViewCell?

What I have done:

```
    [swipeLeft setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];
    [swipeRight setCancelsTouchesInView:NO];


-(void)swipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    BOOL touchedInsideCell = NO;
    CGPoint touchedPoint = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
    for (PCFCustomScheduleCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) {
        CGRect cellFrame = cell.frame;
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(cellFrame, touchedPoint)) {
            touchedInsideCell = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (touchedInsideCell == NO) {
            if (recordOfDay < 5)  {
                recordOfDay++;
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }

    }else {
        //I need to pass the touch to the UITableViewCell, as the swipe to delete feature is not working
    }
}
```

I have already returned YES in the canEditRowAtIndexPath method, and it works if I refrain from added these gesture recognizers. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you the delegate of the gesture recogniser and deciding if it should handle touches?

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't think of this. If you post this below, I can mark your answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your class the delegate of the gesture recogniser and then you can decide if the gesture should handle any incoming touches.